# Prevent direct access to composite components by placing them inside /WEB-INF

Tags: security, jsf, jsf-2, composite-component, web-inf

I'm trying to define some composite components in my web application. According to the tutorials i read, i have to place the xhtml files inside a resource folder located in webcontent.
This solution is problematic, given that it would make those files available for public access from an url.
Is there a way to put this components inside the web-inf folder, and make the jsf look for the files there?
If not, is there another way to avoid direct access?

Thanks.

P.S.: I have looked into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059420/where-to-put-composition-componentsjsf-2-0), and if i understood BalusC's answer correctly, what I intend to do is possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Composite components" are not exactly the same as "compositions" in the question/answer you found. The OP was clearly talking about compositions as in `<ui:include>` files which are including `<ui:componsition>` content.

You effectively want to prevent direct access to `/resources`. This can be achieved by adding the following security constraint entry to `web.xml`:

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Restrict direct access to JSF resources</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>JSF resources</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint /><!-- Empty auth constraint! -->
</security-constraint>
```

As per the upcoming JSF 2.2, this would not be necessary anymore as it allows you to move the whole `/resources` folder into `/WEB-INF` by the following configuration entry in `web.xml`:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.WEBAPP_RESOURCES_DIRECTORY</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/resources</param-value> 
</context-param>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, i misunderstood the use of composition in the other post.
I will check the use of security-constraint, I assume it work as a filter blocking http _get_ and _post_ methods. Is this correct?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, it's something like that :) But then performed by container itself instead of some kind of a homegrown filter.